# How can I undo a pull from an empty repository immediately after initialization?

Tags: git

So I added a remote, empty repository to a local repository that was just initialized, and made the mistake of pulling before committing my local changes:

```
git init
git remote add origin <URL>
git add *
git pull origin master
```

Now all my files have been removed because git wrote the empty repo into the local one.

Normally, when pulling, git refused to merge if there were unstaged local changes that needed committing. I'm surprised that this is different with the initial commit.

`git log` shows only the initial commit since I never committed the local changes, so I can't undo the pull using `git reset --hard`. Is there a way to restore my files and if so, how?

Comment: does a `gitk ORIG_HEAD` show you the last state?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a git pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719205/undo-a-git-pull)

Comment: @eckes: no, it shows only the initial commit.

Comment: @CharlesB: the question is the same, however the accepted answer in that other thread don't work in my situation (and has a typo).

Comment: @mpe do you refer to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/ Should show a hidden commit that has your staged files

Comment: @CharlesB: Yes, I mean that answer. The provided command does not do what it advertises. The one in the accepted answer to this question does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the work-flow you gave above, it appears that you staged your files. That should leave some dangling blobs out there, that you should be able to recover.

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

That should commit the changes to a file in .git/lost-found. Something might show up there.

Further discussion: [Recover file after git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107593/recover-file-after-git-pull), [Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head)

Comment: This gives me some files that contain the original content. I can reconstruct my project from them. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If the changes you lost were not committed, git isn't aware of them and cannot recover them. Always commit or stash uncommited changes before taking actions that may modify the state of the working directory.

Comment: While I really appreciate your warning, your answer is not correct (see accepted answer). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I hadn't realized that you'd staged your changes. When you do so, git, of course, becomes aware of them.